# where has the debug tab gone on eclipse 21.1.0

Tags: android, eclipse

i just downloaded and installed adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219 from scratch and followed the install info here http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html

eclipse seem to run ok except now there is no tab for debug on the top right, only Java and the perspective thing. as a result, when i try debug my app, there is no logcat and i can't find it on a menu anywhere

it must be some setup thing i'm doing wrong. can anyone help? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find it here: `Window` -> `Open Perspective` -> `Other...` When opening it from here it will be placed on the top right with the recently used perspectives.

Also the perspective will be opened automatically if a breakpoint is reached.

Comment: that worked, well under perspective i found Debug, so now its ok, thanks